# HTTP to HTTPS redirect rule via command line/script?

Tags: iis

Is there a way to use APPCMD or the like to redirect all http:80 traffic to https:443?  For example an incoming request of:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/some/long/string
```

redirects to:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/
```

I know how to do it in the GUI, however I can't seem to figure out how to do this via a script.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you install URL Rewrite from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=urlrewrite2) you can then run the following AppCmd commands and will set that up for your site (in this case "Default Web Site"):

```
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='Redirect to HTTPS']" 
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].match.url:"(.*)""  
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].conditions.[input='{HTTPS}',pattern='Off']" 
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].action.type:"Redirect"" /"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].action.url:"https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}""
```

But also thought to mention that you could just have a web.config file in your content that is copied around so you would never need to actually run a command line like this since that configuration would be part of your site which simplifies deployment.

And just for completeness that will generate the following web.config entries:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - the appcmd worked.  I just want to add that if you are going to do this in powershell you need to change the inside double quotes to single quotes.  I really appreciate it!